# Does anyone know of a Powerball API?

Tags: javascript, api

I've already [Googled](http://bit.ly/19gguaW) about as much as anyone can on this subject, but seem to keep coming up near empty handed. When I say near, I mean, I've found 2 sets of script files on [this](http://www.lotteryusa.com/powerball/) site that help. I can use the two files [[DynamicFeedRequest.js](http://www.lotteryusa.com/js/DynamicFeedRequest.js) && [getfeeddata.js]](http://www.mylottoadserv.com/services/lottofeeds/js/getfeeddata.js?feedtype=results&aff=33075&lotteryid=25&feedid=2&xsltfile=/widget-state.php&targetid=divlottofeed25) to get the info I'd like, the problem is, I can't make it more singular. I'm trying to find a simple REST API or something of that nature that I can make a quick ajax call to for sake of a Plug-In I'm writing.

I'm still working on breaking the js files down, and that may be my end result, but I was hoping another out there might know of a simple API where I can get the "*Last 10 Winning Number Sets*"? Anyone?

Comment: I'm kind of curious about this myself. It would help with a plug in I wrote as well!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** as noted in the comments, this link no longer works. Use the information in the comments if you come across this answer.

Powerball publishes all numbers in a single text file [here](http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt).  You can write something that reads this data in.

Comment: Good find, you can't ask for cleaner data than that.

Comment: OH THANK YOU! As soon as I can accept answer I will! That's perfect!

Comment: Alternatively, use F12->Network when browsing their site, and you see the APIs: https://www.powerball.com/api/v1/numbers/powerball/recent10?_format=json

Comment: Megamillions URL would be https://www.megamillions.com/cmspages/utilservice.asmx/GetLatestDrawData

Comment: The json feeds are nice, but they don't list all the numbers.

Comment: The text file link is no longer working, but per @WhiteN01se's comment above, the APIs work. There are several of them that you'd need to hit for complete data -- [number of winners](https://powerball.com/api/v1/draw-summary/powerball?_format=json), [estimated jackpot](https://powerball.com/api/v1/estimates/powerball?_format=json), [winning numbers](https://powerball.com/api/v1/numbers/powerball/recent?_format=json)

Comment: @Robbert, adding to WhiteN01se's and cfiske's comments. I get lottery data from: [PB next](https://powerball.com/api/v1/estimates/powerball?_format=json), [PB last 10](https://powerball.com/api/v1/numbers/powerball/recent10?_format=json), [MM next](https://www.megamillions.com/cmspages/utilservice.asmx/GetLatestDrawData), [MM last 10](https://www.megamillions.com/cmspages/utilservice.asmx/GetDrawingPagingData?pageSize=10&startDate=&endDate=&pageNumber=1). Oddly, PB's _field_next_draw_date_ is UTC but has no Z terminator. I have to convert it to my local time zone or it presents as next day.

Comment: You can use this one: https://rapidapi.com/avoratechnology/api/powerball. It does calls for the last winning drawing, the last ten winning drawings, all winning drawings, statistics and many others.

Comment: Powerball updated its API and these links no longer produce a JSON response.

Comment: Hello.  I am going to take one for the team.  Since they took away the json API from us, I have created my own.  This has the same output as the old official Powerball API.  You can use this link to get the results of the last three drawings.

https://www.ddddesigns.com/json/powerball

Comment: @DennisDay How did you get the data to make that json?

Comment: I scrape the powewrball.com site (HTML) and save the numbers in MySQL.  Then I generate the json via PHP.